# Probability of selecting three of the same thing from a collection

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

**Question**: A collection of 6 items is to be randomly drawn from a bin containing 100 good items and 8 
defective items. What is the probability that exactly 3 of the items chosen are defective?

**My Attempt**: Well we know that in total there are 108 items. We know that you have a 8/108 chance of the first item being a defective one. I don't understand however, how we can figure out the other items, because it's dependent upon whether the first one was defective or not.

If anyone could explain this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

The number $X$ of the defective items in the sample followes the [hypergeometric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) with parameters $N=108$ (population size), $K=8$ ("successes" in the population) and $n=6$ (sample size). Thus $$P(X=3)=\frac{\binom{8}{3}\binom{108-8}{6-3}}{\binom{108}{6}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose all $8$ defective items belong in one set. If you want to choose $3$ defective items from this set, then you're looking for $3$-element subsets of this set. There are $\binom{8}{3}$ different $3$-element subsets of $8$-element set. If you follow this reasoning you get:

$$
\frac{\binom{8}{3}\binom{100}{3}}{\binom{108}{6}}
$$

Since you also need to select, $3$ good items from a $100$ and total of $6$ items from a $108$.